# Is there an option in Glue to update a table?

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have data partitioned by day stored in S3, i.e. `customer/year=2020/month=04/day=05`, and I have a crawler cataloging that data. Data arrives daily. Is there an option in Glue to update the customer table in that example? For instance, let's say that new customers are discovered on day=06, then, it got added to the table, but let's say that existing customers have updated fields, then, is there an option to only update the table? Or is it a new record to the table?

Currently, when configuring a crawler to discover partitioned data, the partition fields get added to the record. I guess what I'd like to know is if it's possible to constantly have a table representing the latest state of the data?

Thanks in advance.
K

Comment: Your crawled table is merely a reflection of your data in s3 or in the actual source location. When you crawl, only the metadata is kept i.e the schema, partition information, version and the location of the data. Your ETL process is the one that is supposed to cater for incoming customer data. You can make use bookmarks [1], to make sure you do not reprocess data that you have already processed. Hope that answers your question.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html

Answer (score 1):

Summarising your question

```
Is there an option in Glue to update the customer table in that example?
```

You can only add new partitions to the table when they come in. This means that if you have a customer record in the previous partitions and the a new record came in day=06 for the same customer, this new record comes in with a new partition date and is visible along with the data for the same customer with previous partitioned dates. You cannot update the same customer record (if its on s3), unless and until you read all the files and do some sort of ranking to create a new dataset.

Comment: Ok then, one of the option is to use a Glue job or other to process the data getting the latest state and store it in a DB or S3... Let me know if anyone else is doing this type of work and what would their approach be? Thanks.

Comment: We do something slightly similar. The idea would be that we have a new file everyday and we have a copy of a file that has all the changes till date. When we process a new file we build a new copy of the full file with all the latest changes and also have the delta changes in a separate folder for even more granular viewing of delta changes over time.

Comment: It looks like what I have too. In terms of implementation, I'm thinking of a Spark job to read the latest state of customers that will be stored on the side and also the daily data newly sent. Doing a unionAll of both, grouping by customer id and returning the latest record for each customer. So that we produce the latest dataset and probably store it under an S3 bucket partitioned year/month/day. Thanks.